# Fazendo Media em Java

Tags: java, eclipse

A faculdade me passou um código na aula introdutória de Java mas um erro aparece

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Media {
    
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        //TODO auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        double media,nota1,nota2;
        System.out.println("Digite a nota 1");
        nota1=Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Digite a nota 2");
        nota2=Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
        media=(nota1+nota2) / 2.0;
        System.out.println("A sua média é:"+ media);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

o erro é:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

    at programacao1.Media.main(Media.java:5)
```

SOCORRO!

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui soluncionar! acontece que eu criei a classe e não importei pro projeto.
A solução foi acressentar ao topo do código `package programacao1` sendo programacao1 o nome do meu projeto portanto o código ficaria assim:

```
package programacao1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Media {
    
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        //TODO auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        double media,nota1,nota2;
        System.out.println("Digite a nota 1");
        nota1=Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Digite a nota 2");
        nota2=Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
        media=(nota1+nota2) / 2.0;
        System.out.println("A sua média é:"+ media);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).